# "dual inheritance" pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

So an `A*` pointer can point to any object having a base `A`, and a `B*` pointer can point to any object with a base `B*`. Is there anyway to make a pointer that can only point to objects that have both `A` and `B` as a base?

I'd also want it to be something I can store as a class member (perhaps a smart version) without making that class a template class.

**Edit:**

@KerrekSB asked below what the point of this is. Basically I want to make a number of pure virtual base classes (i.e. interfaces) say `printable`, `flyable`, `something_else_able` etc.

And then I might have a new class which requires in it's constructor requires something which is both `printable` and `flyable`. If it was just one or the other, you could store it as a (smart) pointer and let polymorphism take care of the rest, but I'm trying to work out how to do this if the class uses both bases.

Comment: A `void` pointer, or a pointer to a base class that A and B share.

Comment: @PawełStawarz: I think the OP wants something more restrictive than that (witness the "only").

Comment: @PawełStawarz A `void` pointer can point to anything, not just `A` or `B`. And a pointer to a shared base class can point to other subclasses of that base as well.

Comment: Your question is imprecise. Do you require the pointer type have valid conversions to `A*` and `B*`?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use a type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename A, typename B> struct has_two_bases
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_base_of<A, T>:: value &&
                               std::is_base_of<B, T>:: value> { }
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(has_two_bases<T, A, B>::value, "Not a good type");
T * p;
```

Comment: I've just added a clarification to my question. Can I store such a pointer in a class without making it a template class?

Comment: @Clinton: There isn't a single such type. There could be any number of types that satisfy your constraints. It's fairly unclear what problem you're trying to solve here...

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this fit the bill?

```
class W {};                                                                 
class X {};                                                                 
class Y {};                                                                 
class Z : public X, public Y {};                                            

template <typename A, typename B>                                           
class DualPointer {                                                         
 public:                                                                    
  template <typename T>                                                     
  DualPointer(T *t) : a_ptr_(t), b_ptr_(t) {}                               
  operator A*() { return a_ptr_; }                                          
  operator B*() { return b_ptr_; }                                          
 private:                                                                   
  A *a_ptr_;                                                                
  B *b_ptr_;                                                                
};                                                                          

int main() {                                                                
  Z z;                                                                      
  DualPointer<X, Y> p(&z);                                                  
  X *x = p;                                                                 
  Y *y = p;                                                                 
  return 0;                                                                 
}
```

Or if you're in a C++11 mood:

```
template <typename... Ts>                                                   
class MultiPointer;                                                         

template <typename T, typename... Rest>                                     
class MultiPointer<T, Rest...> : public MultiPointer<Rest...> {             
 public:                                                                    
  template <typename U>                                                     
  MultiPointer(U *u) : MultiPointer<Rest...>(u), ptr_(u) {};                
  operator T*() { return ptr_; }                                            
 private:                                                                   
  T *ptr_;                                                                  
};                                                                          

template <>                                                                 
class MultiPointer<> {                                                      
 public:                                                                    
  MultiPointer(void *) {}                                                   
};                                                                          

int main() {                                                                
  Z z;                                                                      
  MultiPointer<X, Y> p(&z);                                                 
  X *x = p;                                                                 
  Y *y = p;                                                                 
  return 0;                                                                 
}
```

If you're worried about the double storage of pointers, this approach doesn't work. See comments below this answer as to why incorporating Paweł's suggestion of using a union, which works if and only if all the pointers are numerically identical (that is, there's no multiple inheritance or other shenanigans using adjusted this pointers going on), is unsafe and basically useless.

```
// DON'T USE THIS VARIANT!!!!
template <typename... Ts>                                                   
class MultiPointer {                                                        
 public:                                                                    
  MultiPointer(void *) {}                                                   
};                                                                          

template <typename T, typename... Rest>                                     
class MultiPointer<T, Rest...> {                                            
 public:                                                                    
  template <typename U> MultiPointer(U *u) : rest_(u) { ptr_ = u; };        
  template <typename U> operator U*() const { return rest_; }               
  operator T*() const { return ptr_; }                                      
 private:                                                                   
  union {                                                                   
    T *ptr_;                                                                
    MultiPointer<Rest...> rest_;                                            
  };                                                                        
};
```

Comment: In the "single pointer storage" part of your answer: "if and only if all the pointers are numerically identical" I only see one possibility for a type `T` to have its super class pointers `A*` and `B*` pointing to the same address: if either `A` or `B` derives from the other and `T` derives from `A` or `B`, respectively. And it's clearly about multiple inheritance, where we don't want such a situation in most cases.

Comment: leemes, it's implementation dependent, but in many implementations the pointers will be numerically identical in the absence of vtables (that is, the absence of virtual functions).

Comment: So they store their content at the same place, i.e. overlapping? That would be a cool compression. Seriously, how is that possible? `class A { int x; }; class B { float y; }; class C : A, B {};` Now, `x` and `y` would share the same memory if `(void*)(A*)c == (void*)(B*)c`

Comment: Heh, good catch. As indicated by my code, I was testing with empty classes. Which I suppose might occasionally be used by a pattern like this (as behavior mix-ins), but that's definitely on the weird side. And a compliant implementation *could* share base pointers if there's no constraint that offsetof(first element) == 0 (don't recall). Still, I hereby retract my comment, and will update the answer to make it clear that playing games with unions doesn't make sense.

Comment: You might want to make your conversion operators const.

Answer (score 1):

While you could write a pointer wrapper class (similar to "smart pointers", but not so smart in this case) which only accepts pointers to types derived from `A` and `B`, **dereferencing them becomes ambiguous**. This is a *conceptual* problem you can't solve with *any* method.

But you could provide two functions `toA()` and `toB()` and/or conversion operators in order to retrieve a pointer to one of the base classes. But as said, you can't (nicely) overload `operator*` to retrieve the base reference depending on the context (depending on whether an `A*` or a `B*` is needed in the context). Same with `operator->`.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class DualPointer {
    A *a; // We need two separate pointers because their distance is not known
    B *b;
public:
    template<typename T>
    DualPointer(T* object) :
        a(object),
        b(object)
    { }

    A *toA() const { return a; }
    B *toB() const { return b; }

    operator A* () const { return a; }
    operator B* () const { return b; }
};
```

Using SFINAE you can also allow a function template which has the actual type as the template parameter, like `to<MyBaseA>()`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<A, T>::value, T*>::type
to() {
    return a;
}
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<B, T>::value, T*>::type
to() {
    return b;
}
```

[Demonstration of this wrapper class](http://ideone.com/93vnpg)

You can then add such a pointer as a class member as requested in your question:

```
class MyClass {
    DualPointer<MyBaseA, MyBaseB> pointer;
};
```

and access the pointer like:

```
pointer.toA()->memberFunctionOfA();
```

If your types `A` and `B` are fixed, then either drop the "template" line and replace `A` and `B` accordingly, or add a `typedef DualPointer<MyBaseA, MyBaseB> MyAOrB;`

---

Expanding on this, you could say **one of the two base classes**, say the first, is your "main" base class. That could then be the one the pointer acts *like*, so the one returned by `operator*` and `operator->`. The two operators would then look like:

```
A * operator-> () const { return a; }
A & operator* () const { return *a; }
```

Then the call from above can become as easy as

```
pointer->memberFunctionOfA();
```

**but not simultaneously**

```
pointer->memberFunctionOfB();
```